# Replacing multiple values in CSV

Tags: json, pandas, python-3.8

I have a directory full of CSVs. A script I use loads each CSV via a Loop and corrects commonly known errors in several columns prior to being imported into an SQL database. The corrections I want to apply are stored in a JSON file so that a user can freely add/remove any corrections on-the-fly without altering the main script.

My script works fine for 1 value correction, per column, per CSV. However I have noticed that 2 or more columns per CSV now contain additional errors, as well as more than one correction per column is now required.

Here is relevant code:

```
with open('lookup.json') as f:
    translation_table = json.load(f)

for filename in gl.glob("(Compacted)_*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=object)

    #... Some other enrichment...

    # Extract the file "key" with a regular expression (regex)
    filekey = re.match(r"^\(Compacted\)_([A-Z0-9-]+_[0-9A-z]+)_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}.csv$", filename).group(1)

    # Use the translation tables to apply any error fixes
    if filekey in translation_table["error_lookup"]:
        tablename = translation_table["error_lookup"][filekey]
        df[tablename[0]] = df[tablename[0]].replace({tablename[1]: tablename[2]})
    else:
        pass
```

And here is the lookup.json file:

```
    }
    "error_lookup": {
        "T7000_08": ["MODCT", "C00", -5555],
        "T7000_17": ["MODCT", "C00", -5555],
        "T7000_20": ["CLLM5", "--", -5555],
        "T700_13": ["CODE", "100T", -5555]
    }
```

For example if a column (in a CSV that includes the key "T7000_20") has a new erroneous value of ";;" in column **CLLM5**, how can I ensure that values that contain "--" and ";;" are replaced with "-5555"? How do I account for another column in the same CSV too?

Comment: Or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the JSON file?  The example below would edit Column A (old1 → new 1 and old2 → new2) and would make similar changes to Column B:

```
{'error_lookup': {'T7000_20': {'colA': ['old1', 'new1', 'old2', 'new2'],
                               'colB': ['old3', 'new3', 'old4', 'new4']}}}
```

The JSON parsing gets more complex, in order to handle current use case and new requirements.

Comment: I can change the JSON file, however by inheriting your example, I get a KeyError. I believe this is because the line         df[tablename[0]] = df[tablename[0]].replace({tablename[0]: tablename[1]})
cannot find a suitable value in loc[0] and [1]

Comment: {
    "error_lookup": {
        "T7000_08": ["MODCT", "C00", -5555],
        "T7000_17": ["MODCT", "C00", -5555],
        "T7000_20": {"CLLM5": ["--", -5555, ";;", -5555]},
        "T700_13": ["CODE", "100T", -5555]
    }
}